# Constant sum suvey data!

Tags: survey, compositional-data

I have conducted a survey where respondents had to allocate 100 points over 3 choices. There were 8 questions like this in total, where the choices were the same but the attributes on the choices were different. The independent variables I have are gender, age, highest education, money spend per week on groceries and diet. Now I would like to see if there are any significant differences between the 3 options over all 8 questions, which independent variables have a significant effect on what choices. I haven't done much in statistics so I'm quiet lost.

Comment: What you are looking at is a multinomial comparison for each of your independent variables.  Start by researching this to see if it helps.

Comment: Data like that are called "compositional data".  I added the relevant tag.  If you click on it, you can see other threads on the topic.